# PHP - auto detect when/if files have been updated

Tags: php

Is there a way in PHP to detect when a file is updated and saved?

If not what would be the best method 'faking' this.

I.e. before a certain action if executed, check the last saved date of the file?

Comment: PHP by itself can only check timestamps, but most OSes these days provide APIs to hook into filesystem operations so you can get 'pinged' when a change occurs. Doing this will depend on which OS you're on.

Comment: @MarcB The operating system would primarily be linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A PHP script would not be able to automatically detect changes to files because the page has to be requested. You could write a script and run a cron (scheduled task) to run every so often. Or use [filemtime()](http://php.net/filemtime) as others have suggested.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`filemtime`](http://php.net/filemtime). It returns a file's "last modified" timestamp. (If you mean running a PHP script when a file is changed, that's not possible using just PHP.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`filemtime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) to find out the modification date of a file. If I understood you correct.

However if you want to keep track of files when they are changed you can still use `filemtime`, but you will have to keep track of the current modified date (e.g. in db or file) and check this value against the current value.

You could use a cronjob to periodically run this php script.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
// outputs e.g.  somefile.txt was last modified: December 29 2002 22:16:23.

$filename = 'somefile.txt';
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "$filename was last modified: " . date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($filename));
}

?>
```

Use [this function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php#example-2199) to get when file was last modified. You can play with data to achieve your task.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way can be to watch for a content change using a hash of the type `crc32`, who have the advantage to have a very low footprint.

```
<?php
$hash = hash_file("crc32","watch.txt");
while ($hash === hash_file("crc32","watch.txt")){
  usleep(100000); // 100ms
}
echo "File changed";
```

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check
>
> A **C**yclic **R**edundancy **C**heck (CRC) (...) Blocks of data entering these systems get a short
> check value attached, based on the remainder of a polynomial division
> of their contents. On retrieval, **the calculation is repeated** and, in
> the event the check values do not match, corrective action can be
> taken

List of algos:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php